# How to capture video using Intent and set path of recorded and limit recording time

Tags: android, video, android-intent, capture, filepath

I use an example of recording video using intent based on

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED);
```

For time limit I have used: `intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 5);`
This records 5 seconds and then stop automatically.

I have used example from URL:
http://android-er.blogspot.cz/2011/04/start-video-recording-using.html
This example is for me interesting because works on all my devices and is easy to implement.

Is it possible to set the path to save recorded video ?
Let's say simple I need video to save to a specified file "myrecordedvideo.mp4" to a specified folder and need video to have exactly 5 seconds. Is it possible to make it easy way with this Intent ?

Answer (score 12):

To set the time limit and set the path to save the video

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 30);
takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"videocapture_example.mp4");

startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```